# Obtener color al dar click PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Hola básicamente quiero saber como obtener el color de algún elemento al dar click sobre de el.

Ya intente Invocando al Color picker widget de PyQt :

```
def color_picker(self):
    color = QtGui.QColorDialog.getColor()
    self.styleChoice.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" % color.name())
```

pero quiero obtener el color de cualquier punto en el que de click.

Comment: Hola Angel, no me queda muy claro lo que quieres ¿Deseas obtener el color de fondo de unos widgets determinados cuando se hace click en ellos?¿Qué widgets?¿Con qué tipo de fondo (sólido, imágen, etc)? Por otro lado, usas la etiqueta `pyqt5` en específico pero en el código que muestras (para seleccionar el color de fondo vía color-picker) no usas pyqt5, en pyqt5 `QColorDialog` se encuentra en `PyQt5.QtWidgets` al igual que el resto de widgets.

Comment: si me di cuenta que es código de pyqt4 fue un error en la redacción.

Comment: Básicamente o que quiero hacer es obtener el color de cualquier objeto en la pantalla al dar click.  Mas o menos como lo que hace el QColorDialog. pero sin abrir el dialogo de selección de color